# RHEL 7 psql: FATAL: Ident authentication failed

Tags: redhat, postgresql, rhel7

I am trying to start the PostgreSQL database, but it's always failing.

Command I am trying:
`psql -h localhost -U postgres`  resulting error: 
`psql: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"`.

Contents of `/var/lib/pgsql/9.5/data/pg_hba.conf` is as follows:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            ident
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 ident
```

I recently made the change for the `pg_hba.conf` file, I am assuming I don't have to restart the postgres.  I followed this [solution](https://serverfault.com/a/406607/192241) but no help. Any suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: `peer` is the local version of `ident`.  Both options expect that the user running the `psql` command is the same as the user you are trying to log in as.